# Browsing private and public files in IMCE

Tags: 7, files

I have set up a public and a private file location (/admin/config/media/file-system).
The private file location is not under the Drupal directory ( it's /opt/private_files ).
I have set the "Default download method" to "Private local files served by Drupal."

I have configured a profile for IMCE ( /admin/config/media/imce ) called "User-1"
with a "Directory Path" of {root}/. "Including subdirectories".

I have assigned this profile to the role "administrator" under "Role-profile assignments" for both "PUBLIC FILES" as well as "PRIVATE FILES".

But when I access IMCE directly using mydomain.com/imce I only see the private files.

How can I switch or access the public files ?

Answer (score -2):

While writing this question I found it:

You can access the public files like this:
mydomain.com/imce/public

and the private files:
mydomain.com/imce/private

Comment: How can you access these paths? I see the path to my private_files in the top of IMCE file browser, but I can't enter the path you mentioned "mydomain.com/imce/private" ?

Comment: just put it in the browser address field, not in the IMCE window. I added two links in the Drupal shortcut bar to both for my editors.